# Laravel: Actively listening events from external service

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, asterisk

I'm developing a PBX monitoring app with Laravel. On PBX side, [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org) is managing the calls.

I can use [PAMI](https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI) client to receive all events from [Asterisk Manager Interface](https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-api/). If I simply run this script from console, all the events on Asterisk are printed on the screen in real time:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl as PamiClient;
use PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage;
use PAMI\Listener\IEventListener;


$pamiClientOptions = array(
    'host' => '',
    'scheme' => 'tcp://',
    'port' => 5038,
    'username' => '',
    'secret' => '',
    'connect_timeout' => 10000,
    'read_timeout' => 10000
);

$pamiClient = new PamiClient($pamiClientOptions);


// Open the connection
$pamiClient->open();

$pamiClient->registerEventListener(function (EventMessage $event) {
    var_dump($event);
});
$running = true;
// Main loop
while($running) {
    $pamiClient->process();
    usleep(1000);
}
// Close the connection
$pamiClient->close();
```

What I'm trying to do is implementing events&listeners in Laravel with PAMI. But it doesn't seem to work.

I have registered the event and listener on `EventServiceProvider` class:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\AmiEventOccurred' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogAmiEvent',
    ],
```

My event class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;

class AmiEventOccurred
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $pamiClientOptions = array(
            'host' => getenv('PAMI_HOST'),
            'scheme' => getenv('PAMI_SCHEME'),
            'port' => getenv('PAMI_PORT'),
            'username' => getenv('PAMI_USERNAME'),
            'secret' => getenv('PAMI_SECRET'),
            'connect_timeout' => getenv('PAMI_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'),
            'read_timeout' => getenv('PAMI_READ_TIMEOUT'),
        );

        $pamiClient = new \PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl($pamiClientOptions);

        // Open the connection
        $pamiClient->open();

        $pamiClient->registerEventListener(function (\PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage $message) {
            $this->message = $message;
        });

        $running = true;

        // Main loop
        while($running) {
            $pamiClient->process();
            usleep(1000);
        }

        // Close the connection
        $pamiClient->close();

    }
}
```

My listener class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\AmiEventOccurred;

class LogAmiEvent
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  AmiEventOccurred  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(AmiEventOccurred $event)
    {
        Log::debug(print_r($event, true));
    }
}
```

Is this a correct approach? Is it possible to actively listen to another service in real time with Laravel events, or should I develop another app for it to run in real time on the background and trigger Laravel events when necessary?

Answer (score 1):

All of this code doesn't belong in an event. An event is just for announcing that something has happened, and containing all of the important information about what it was.  Your code for running a client and sleeping and all of that should be somewhere else, likely an artisan command that your kernel keeps running.  Then in that code, when something happens, you trigger a simple event with the message for any listeners to act on:

```
$pamiClient->registerEventListener(function (\PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage $message) {
     new AmiMessageReceived($message);
});
```